# JPQL left join query with OR does not yield desired results (one side of OR does not work)

Tags: jpa

We have two JPA entities `BloodDonor` and `LastDonation` linked bidirectionally. `LastDonation` owns the *foreign key*. `BloodDonor` contains the following JPQL query.

```
SELECT e FROM BloodDonor e 
LEFT JOIN e.lastDonation l 
WHERE e.name LIKE :name AND 
(l IS EMPTY OR e.lastDonation.lastDonationDate < :fourMonthsAgo) 
ORDER BY e.createDate DESC
```

Running this query produces the same result as a query constructed without `l IS EMPTY`. It does not include `BloodDonor`s where its `lastDonation` has not been set.

The following query works as expected.

```
SELECT e FROM BloodDonor e 
WHERE e.name LIKE :name AND 
e.lastDonation IS EMPTY
ORDER BY e.createDate DESC
```

What's wrong with the first query and what can be done to sort it out?

Answer (score 1):

Change `is empty` to `is null`, works in my project.

`is empty` should be used with `@<n>ToMany` and `is null` for `@<n>ToOne` relations, but I would expect an exception from JPA provider in case of misuse, and not a query that "works" but doesn't give expected results.

Comment: The query is working if I change `e.lastDonation.lastDonationDate < :fourMonthsAgo` to `l.lastDonationDate < :fourMonthsAgo` whether `is empty` or `is null` is used.

Comment: Strange, in my project when I use an equivalent query, like `l is empty or l.something = 3` it does not work. Works only with `l is null`. I'm using Hibernate 4.3.5

Comment: I'm using Hibernate 4.3.6. The project is [here](https://bitbucket.org/infovillavendor/blooddonation). Not my project but a project done by a newbie I am mentoring.

Comment: Just tested other variants in my project, weather `l.lastDonationDate` or `e.lastDonation.lastDonationDate` is used on the right side of the `OR`, they only work with `is null`. Not sure why we have different behaviour. Glad to see you have a combination that works though, one way or the other :)

Comment: Java's ORM frameworks have lots of examples of unexpected behaviour like this for us to discover. 

P.S. Thanks for taking an interest in my problem and trying to help solve it. I appreciate it.